# Redirect Loop with Laravel 4

Tags: .htaccess, laravel-4, redirect-loop

I have this installed on my local machine. Laravel is installed at the root of a vhost folder, and the document root is the public folder. If i just go to the root url everything is fine. Howerver if I specify a route then I get a redirect loop. For example `www.example.com` works, but `www.example.com/admin` causes a loop. Here's my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Here's my routes.php file:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return 'Hello World';
});

Route::get('testroute',function(){
    return 'Hello World';
});

Route::controller('admin','AdminController');
```

Here's my AdminController.php controller file:

```
<?
class AdminController extends BaseController {

    public function getIndex(){
        return View::make('admin');
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem. Because the document root wasn't the root of the Virtual Host I needed to add this to the .htaccess:

```
RewriteBase /
```

Comment: if you are using apache alias, ie alias /my-site, the RewriteBase most be: 
    RewriteBase /my-site